# count occurrence of a value in multiple columns of a dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to count occurrence of a string value in multiple columns in the entire dataframe, for example :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'type1':['A11','B11','A11','A'],
                     'type2':['A12','C','A12','D11'],
                     'type3':['C','D11','B','D12'],
                     'type4':[np.nan,'E12','C','E']
                    })
df

       type1    type2   type3   type4 
    0   A11      A12      C      NaN     
    1   B11       C      D11     E12     
    2   A11      A12      B       C      
    3    A       D11     D12      E
```

I want to be able to count each distinct value in those 4 columns, like :

```py
value count
 A11    2
 A12    2
 C      3
 B11    1
 D11    2
 D12    1
 E12    3
 B      1
 A      1
 E      1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.stack().value_counts()

C      3
A11    2
A12    2
D11    2
B11    1
E12    1
B      1
A      1
D12    1
E      1
```

if you need the names:

```
df.stack().value_counts().reset_index(name='count').rename({'index':'value'}, axis = 1)
 
  value  count
0     C      3
1   A11      2
2   A12      2
3   D11      2
4   B11      1
5   E12      1
6     B      1
7     A      1
8   D12      1
9     E      1
```

Comment: OP didn't specified, but just to clarify, it returns a serie not a dataframe right? :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).dropna(how='all').sum(1).reset_index()
df1.rename(columns = {'index':'value', 0:'count'}, inplace = True)
df1
```

Output:

| index | value | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1.0 |
| 1 | A11 | 2.0 |
| 2 | A12 | 2.0 |
| 3 | B | 1.0 |
| 4 | B11 | 1.0 |
| 5 | C | 3.0 |
| 6 | D11 | 2.0 |
| 7 | D12 | 1.0 |
| 8 | E | 1.0 |
| 9 | E12 | 1.0 |

Answer (score 2):

Another way: The advantage of this method is, if one wants to keep understand the data based on `type1`, `type2`, etc one just need to do `reset_index()` in step 2.

Original Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type1':['A11','B11','A11','A'],
                     'type2':['A12','C','A12','D11'],
                     'type3':['C','D11','B','D12'],
                     'type4':[np.nan,'E12','C','E']
                    })
```

Stack the data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(), columns = ['colnam'])
```

Then groupby based on required column:

```
print(df1.groupby('colnam')['colnam'].count())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your values using [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), then create a new dataframe and use [`pd.DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) to get your output:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(1,-1)[0], columns = ['type']).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
type
C       3
A11     2
A12     2
D11     2
A       1
B       1
B11     1
D12     1
E       1
E12     1
```